# Does anyone know an easy way to index a JSON formatted object in java?

Tags: java, json, node.js

I'm really new to java, so please forgive me if this is a particularly stupid question.

I have a JSON object that is structured as

```
list {[
  item1: [{title: "title1",
          detail: "detail1"}
          {title: "title2",
          detail: "detail2"}
          ... unit n]
  item2: [{title: "title1",
          detail: "detail1"}
          {title: "title2",
          detail: "detail2"}
          ... unit n]

  ... 

  item n etc
]}
```

And I want to be able to receive an item, and find the matching array (title, description) set from within the object. My issue is that I want to be able to match the item name to the index within the json object. For example, if the item = "nodejs" I'd like to be able to find the "nodejs" array within the list. Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to search through the list for this. I've found several examples showing how to index by number and look for a match but it seems like there should be a better way than just manually going through the list from i=0 i=n and checking the item name against the item title of that index...

I had set this up as a matter of straightforward array referencing, but I realized that because the item is dynamic that doesn't work in the traditional `list.item` format.

If anyone has any tips on how to accomplish this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Parse it to POJOs and create a `Map`.

Comment: You can use Google GSON or Jackson libraries to parse your JSON to POJOs. (Edit: [JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) may be useful.)

Comment: ChristophGiesche I've already got it imported as an object. My issue is just indexing through it.
@Andreas do you have a notable link for the Map? I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials - The Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html). Javadoc for [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Google [`java map`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+map). Do some **research**!

Comment: @Andreas -.- Fair. Thanks man. I'll update the answer soon. If you'd like to throw an answer on saying the above I will accept it so you get some credit.